# How to bookmark and close all tabs with javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have code so far that will save a bookmark of the current tab then close it when i push my WebExtension button. I want the code to save and then close all of the tabs.

```
var currentTab;
var currentBookmark;

// gets active tabe
function callOnActiveTab(callback) {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      for (var tab of tabs) {
        if (tab.active) {
          callback(tab, tabs);
        }
      }
    });
}

/*
 * Add the bookmark on the current page.
 */
function Bookmark() {

    chrome.bookmarks.create({title: currentTab.title, url: currentTab.url}, function(bookmark) {
        currentBookmark = bookmark;
    });

    callOnActiveTab((tab) => {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
    });

}

/*
 * Switches currentTab and currentBookmark to reflect the currently active tab
 */
function updateTab() {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    if (tabs[0]) {
      currentTab = tabs[0];

      chrome.bookmarks.search({url: currentTab.url}, (bookmarks) => {
        currentBookmark = bookmarks[0];
      });
    }
  });
}



function listTabs() {

    Bookmark();

}


chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(listTabs);


chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(updateTab);
// listen to tab switching
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(updateTab);
```

If I add the Bookmark() function to the end of updateTab() function, the button no longer works and when I change tabs it saves that one and exits all tabs.

Comment: An script can only close the windows it open... maybe it can only interact with the active tab? does it run on a page or as extension install in the browser?

Comment: Yes I had read that too but it never opens this page. I open 2 or 3 tabs for testing. It is and extension install in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a bit of your code appears overly complicated for what you appear to be attempting to do. A significant part of your problem with not being able to use the `Bookmark` function to bookmark and remove multiple tabs is that it is relying on a global variable that is changed by an asynchronous event handler which is tracking the active tab. That function can be re-coded to use an argument that is passed in to the function. In that way it can be generally re-used.

Note: I moved the removal of the tab out of the `bookmarkTab` function (what is `Bookmark` in your code). Having it in there, while only calling the function `Bookmark`, is a bad idea. I added a `bookmarkAndRemoveTab()` function which is clearly named for both things that it is doing.

Just the sections associated with your `browserAction` could be:

```
var currentBookmark;  
/* Add a bookmark for a tab
 *   tabsTab - The tabs.Tab object for the tab containing the page to bookmark
 *   callback - Called with the tabs.Tab object when the bookmark is complete
 */
function bookmarkTab(tabsTab, callback) {
    chrome.bookmarks.create({title: tabsTab.title, url: tabsTab.url}, function(bookmark) {
        currentBookmark = bookmark;
        if(typeof callback === 'function'){
            callback(tabsTab);
        }
    });
}
/* Remove a Tab
 *   tabsTab - The tabs.Tab object for the tab to remove
 *   callback - Called with the, now invalid, tab ID of the removed tab
 */
function removeTab(tabsTab, callback){
    let  rememberedId = tabsTab.id; //Unknown if object changes upon removal
    chrome.tabs.remove(rememberedId,function(){
        if(typeof callback === 'function'){
            callback(rememberedId);
        }
    });
}
/* Bookmark and remove a tab once the bookmark has been made
 *   tabsTab - The tabs.Tab object for the tab to remove
 */
function bookmarkAndRemoveTab(tabsTab) {
    //When we get here from the browserAction click, tabsTab is the active tab
    //  in the window where the button was clicked.  But, this function can be used
    //  anytime you have a tabs.Tab object for the tab you want to bookmark and delete.
    bookmarkTab(tabsTab,removeTab);
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(bookmarkAndRemoveTab);
```

Then you could have a function that did `bookmarkAndRemoveTab()` on every tab:

```
/* Bookmark and remove all tabs
 */
function bookmarkAndRemoveAllTabs() {
    //Get all tabs in 'normal' windows:
    //  May want to test. Could want to get all tabs in all windows
    //  Of windowTypes:["normal","popup","panel","devtools", probably only
    //  want  "normal" and "popup" tabs to be bookmarked and closed.
    let queryInfos = [{windowType: 'normal'},{windowType: 'popup'}];
    queryInfos.forEach(function(queryInfo){
        chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
            for (let tab of tabs) {
                bookmarkAndRemoveTab(tab);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: So I implemented your code like: **chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(bookmarkAndRemove‌​AllTabs);** Im still running into the same problem. It will book mark the first tab and then close all of the tabs. When I reopen, only the first one was bookmarked.

Comment: OK, I made the, stupid, choice not to look into the actual process of making a bookmark. It should have been clear and obvious to me that it was asynchronous. I have corrected the code to something that should work. The problem was, probably, that the bookmarking process was initiated, but not completed, prior to the tabs being removed (and Firefox shutting down). Each tab is, now, not removed until after the bookmark has been made.